# Obtaining geom_line values at mid-month for unequally spread geom_points

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2, geom

I need to obtain value at 15th of every month from the geom line created using the reproducible example below. The original geom points are at varied monthly dates depending on data collection days. Appreciate any help possible[image]

```
Value <- c(19.14104, 11.72115, 9.66083, 10.99109, 13.65047, 10.10627, 13.53027, 18.25272, 25.57741)
Dates <- c("07/11/19", "28/11/19", "16/12/19", "10/01/20", "21/01/20", "03/02/20", "04/03/20", "19/03/20", "20/05/20")

df <- data.frame(Value, Dates)
View(df)

df$Dates <- lubridate::dmy(df$Dates)


gpp_plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x=Dates, y=Value), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Dates, y=Value), alpha=0.5) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10, , face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, face = "bold", angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))+
  xlab('') +
  ylab('LI-7810_FCH4_DRY_[nmol+1m-2s-1]') +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %y",breaks = "1 months") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
gpp_plot
```

Comment: The `approx` function in R might be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you could `approx` the `Value` at new dates:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

Dates <- dmy(Dates)

NewDates <- seq(floor_date(min(Dates),'month'),floor_date(max(Dates),'month'),by='month')+days(14)

#[1] "2019-11-15" "2019-12-15" "2020-01-15" "2020-02-15" "2020-03-15" "2020-04-15" "2020-05-15"

NewValue <- approx(Dates,Value,NewDates)$y

df <- data.frame(Value=c(Value,NewValue), Dates=c(Dates,NewDates))


gpp_plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x=Dates, y=Value), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Dates, y=Value), alpha=0.5) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10, , face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, face = "bold", angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %y",breaks = "1 months") +
  ylab('LI-7810_FCH4_DRY_[nmol+1m-2s-1]') +

  theme(legend.position="none")
gpp_plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! -- is there a way to add spline instead of a line in the above approx function. I did not seem to find method ='spline' for the above function. do you recommend any work around?